# Using lxml and path to parse xml, but get empty list if it has xmlns declarations

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I have an xml file that I need to parse the value of a tag. The `XPATH` for the element is `"//provider"`. How would I use `lxml` to parse this tag? This is the start of the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://...">
    <provider>testmovieprovider</provider>
    <language>ja-JP</language>
    <!-- more stuff -->
</package>
```

The following is what I have tried:

```
>>> f = open(file)
>>> xml = f.read()
>>> node = etree.fromstring(xml)
>>> provider=node.xpath('//provider')
>>> provider
[] # (This returns an empty set, instead of the provider name, 'testmovieprovider'.)
```

Comment: Show us the sample xml file or show us content of `xml`

Comment: Take a look at this http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes link. and try xpath with namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try an XPath like this:

`/*/*[local-name()='provider']`

Comment: Thanks, why does yours work, but using the normal `//provider` fails to capture it?

Comment: @David42 - It's because of the default namespace. It's tricky because there is no prefix. If your xmlns was something like `xmlns:foo="http://..."`, you could use `//foo:provider`. Also, I didn't use `//` because it's inefficient. It's more efficient to use a more explicit path if you already know it. However, you could have  also used: `//*[local-name()='provider']`.

Answer (score 3):

Try the xpath with `xml namespace`

I added the namespace  `xmlns="http://codespeak.net/ns/test1"`

and than used the following code

```
>>> xml_node = etree.fromstring(st)
>>> xml_node.xpath('//t:provider/text()',namespaces={'t': 'http://codespeak.net/ns/test1'})
['testmovieprovider']
>>>
```

My `st` string is

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <package xmlns="http://codespeak.net/ns/test1">
 <provider>testmovieprovider</provider>
 <language>ja-JP</language>
 <!-- more stuff -->
 </package>'
```